# How do I conditionally show/not show a Tab in React Native using Expo Tabs

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

Like the heading I want to conditionally show a tab based on an object data thats stored in the AsyncStorage.

app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

interface UserDetails {
  isTeacher?: boolean;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
}
const TabsLayout = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState<UserDetails>({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
   const getUserDetails = async () => {
      const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userDetails");
      setUserDetails(JSON.parse(user));
   }
   getUserDetails();
    
  }, []);
  
  console.log(userDetails.isAdmin,'zzzzz');
  
  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, size }) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === "home") {
            iconName = focused ? "home" : "home-outline";
          } else if (route.name === "community") {
            iconName = focused ? "people" : "people-outline";
          } else if (route.name === "chat") {
            iconName = focused ? "chatbubbles" : "chatbubbles-outline";
          } else if (route.name === "profile") {
            iconName = focused ? "person" : "person-outline";
          }
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={"black"} />;
        },
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          color: "black",
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "white",
        },
      })}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="home"
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: "Home" }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="community"
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: "Community" }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="chat"
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: "Chat" }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="profile"
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: "Profile" }}
      />
      {userDetails.isAdmin &&<Tabs.Screen  ---> conditional rendering 
        name="verification"
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: "Verification" }}
      />}
      
      
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default TabsLayout;
```

The userDetails = {isAdmin : false,}. It shows an error

> Layout children must be of type Screen, all other children are ignored. To use custom children, create a custom . Update Layout Route at: "app/(tabs)/_layout".

Edit: Got it working now because I read the docs(Was pretty stupid not to go there the first thing.). Here is the updated change.

```
<Tabs.Screen
        name="verification"
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: "Verification",
        href: !(userDetails.isAdmin)? null : "/verification"  }}
      />
```

Comment: Take a look at docs: https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/tabs/#hiding-a-tab.